# Docker linked containers, Docker Networks, Compose Networks - how should we now 'link' containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have an existing app that comprises of 4 docker containers running on the same host. They have been linked together using the `link` command.

However, after some upgrades of docker, the `link` behaviour has been deprecated, and changed it seems. We are having issues where containers are loosing the link to each other now.

So, docker says to use the new `Network` feature over `link`ed containers.  But I can't see how this works.

If 2 containers are in the same network, are the same `ENV` vars automatically exposed on the containers as if they were linked?

Or is the hosts file updated with the correct container name / ip addresses ? Even after a `docker restart` ?

I can't see in the docs how a  container can find the location of another in its network?

Also, `compose` looks to have a simple set up for linking containers, and may automate some of this - would compose be the way to go for defining multi container apps? Or is it too soon to run it in production?

Does `compose` support multiple host configuration as well?

at some point in the future we will probably need to move one of the containers to a different host....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If 2 containers are in the same network, are the same ENV vars automatically exposed on the containers as if they were linked?

no, you would now have to use the container names as their hostnames. The new network feature has no idea which ports will be used. Think of this as 2 computers plugged on the same network hub. Both can address the other one by its hostname.

> is the hosts file updated with the correct container name / ip addresses ? Even after a docker restart ?

yes, `/etc/hosts` files for all containers which are part of a network will be updated live by the docker engine.

> I can't see in the docs how a container can find the location of another in its network?

Using the container name. See the [Connect containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#connect-containers) section of the *Work with network commands* doc:
*Once connected, the containers can communicate using another container’s IP address or name.*

> Also, compose looks to have a simple set up for linking containers, and may automate some of this - would compose be the way to go for defining multi container apps? Or is it too soon to run it in production?

Compose supports the new network feature as beta by offering the `--x-networking` option. You **should not use** it in production yet (current Compose version is 1.5).

Furthermore, the current implementation is a bit inconvenient as we must use the full container name which is composed of the *project name* + `_` + *container name* + `_1`. The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) says the next version (current one is 1.5) will improve this so that we should not have to worry about the *project name* to address containers.

> Does compose support multiple host configuration as well?

Yes, in conjonction with Swarm as detailed in the [overlay network documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed answers.  I'll review compose again when we look to move to a multi host set up, but for now then it sounds like the hosts file is the way forward...

Comment: how would you discover the port that the container was exposing?  Say I have 2 containers, a, which maps port 7474 and b.   B can find A via the `hosts` file - http://a, but is there a way to discover the port that is mapped?    With `link`s you could check an env var....

Comment: There are no port translation within a network. Port can be different only when you _publish_ a container port on the Docker host, not when you just _expose_ a port